# Error using glm::vec< 3 , double >

Tags: c++, linux, glm-math

I am using glm on Windows and OS X.

glm::vec< 3 , double > works fine on both. But when i try to compile this on
Linux it gives me the following message:

error: 'vec' is not a member of 'glm'

Same includes like on Windows and OS X but i can't get this compiling.
Any ideas?

Comment: And how are we supposed to spot the bug in code you didn't post?

Comment: Compile what? Please post your attempt.

Comment: Check version, glm::vec<3, double> is not working on my windows system.

Comment: @Quentin i think thats obvious - just the line "glm::vec< 3 , double> test" is the problem. I included "glm/glm.hpp" on all systems but it generates an error on Linux

Comment: @Ragnar I can only guess that the version of GLM you have on your Linux is not up-to-date. In fact, I can't find any documentation for `glm::vec` (although I did find it in the source code on GitHub).

Answer (score 0):

Yes! It works now. I think it was in fact a version thing. I deleted the old 'glm' directory in /usr/include and downloaded the newest version.

@Quentin  @Jeka - Thank you :)